# Deploy WebSharper.Suave web application to Heroku

Tags: heroku, f#, heroku-toolbelt, websharper, suave

I can not understand what I need to change to make it. 
I created a [demo project](https://github.com/fpawel/WebsahrperSuaveHerokuExample1) from [this blogpost](http://websharper.com/blog-entry/4556/announcing-websharper-suave) with app.json and Procfile:

```
web: fsharpi-heroku WebsahrperSuaveHerokuExample1.sln
```

Next, I tried to deploy it to Heroku in accordance with [these](https://suave.io/heroku.html) recommendations:

```
heroku create websahrper-with-suave-example --buildpack https://github.com/SuaveIO/mono-script-buildpack.git
heroku git:remote -a websahrper-with-suave-example
git push heroku master
```

There was an error in Heroku when building the project:

```
...
Import process completed.
-----> packages.config found, installing dependencies with nuget
Cannot open assembly 'install': No such file or directory.
!     Push rejected, failed to compile SuaveFramework app
```

Could you suggest me a solution if there is one?

Comment: You might need to compile it first and run the executable.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried here:

https://github.com/SuaveIO/heroku-getting-started

Fork it and click the Deploy to Heroku button.

Comment: Yes, I have done this successfully. This is a **script-based** demo project, but the question is how to deploy existed project with a **directory with a .sln solution**. [This](https://suave.io/heroku.html) article says:

*Your application needs to be either a single script app.fsx (plus a Heroku Procfile and dummy.sln file) OR a   **directory with a .sln solution** (plus a Heroku Procfile)*

Answer (score 2):

Don't have the rep to comment on the above, but ademar's solution should cover as well as long as you don't have a file named "app.fsx"

The heroku buildpack checks to see if there is a script, then checks for a solution:
https://github.com/SuaveIO/mono-script-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile#L66

Just make sure there is a .sln file in the project directory (can be empty, just needs to be present) or fork the buildpack and just make it default run `mono $YOURPROJECT` in the compile step.

Answer (score 1):

When using an sln instead of a script, you need to change your Procfile to:

> web: mono *Path*/execName.exe

Comment: What should Path be? Something like `bin/debug`?

Comment: @brianberns mine is "src/ProjectFolder/bin/Release/execName.exe"