# Why does a record in an array cause a type initializer error in heroku?

Tags: heroku, f#, typeinitializeexception

I'm deploying an F# app to heroku as a script, and I'm having very strange problems. I'm getting the following error in the cases indicated below, but not the others:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'FSI_0007+Test[]' from
>   assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x410a5830 +
>   0x000b7> in :0

Error case:

```
type Test = { Test: string }
printfn "%A" [|{Test = "test"}|]  <--- error here
```

Working cases:

```
printfn "%A" [|"test"|]

type Test = { Test: string }
printfn "%A" {Test = "test"}

printfn "%A" [{Test = "test"}]
```

So it appears that I can't put records in arrays, but I can put any built-in types in arrays.  Also, I can put records in lists.  And records by themselves are fine.

Why does the combination of records plus arrays cause errors?

I'm using the buildpack here:
https://github.com/SuaveIO/mono-script-buildpack

which uses mono-4.4.2.11.

It doesn't happen with local fsi in visual studio.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Is it just record literals, i.e. can you let-bind a record and use that let binding for the array element?

Comment: Also, what happens if you put a space between the start-of-array operator `[|` and the start-of-record operator `{`? It might be that something is parsing the three characters `[|{` incorrectly as a single token instead of two tokens. If so, then writing `[| {...} |]` should work around the parsing bug.

Comment: @rmunn The error only occurs in heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very much like [this bug in mono](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/652).

I'm not exactly sure which versions of mono were affected by this and the reports in the bug discussion are a bit conflicting - but the latest stable version of mono 4.8.0 seems to work for at least one person...

Another workaround would be to change your website to use `fsproj` so that the code is compiled and started as an executable (rather than using `fsx` file with runs via F# interactive) - I think compiled code does not suffer from this bug (or other potential bugs involving Mono Reflection).

Comment: This looks like the problem!  Unfortunately I switched to using a script because I couldn't figure out how to start the web service when using an sln.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681957/deploy-websharper-suave-web-application-to-heroku has insufficient details.

Comment: @mydogisbox Looks like you need to have `sln` file in the root: https://github.com/SuaveIO/mono-script-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile#L67

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to set my procfile to
"web: mono src/ProjectName/bin/Debug/executable.exe"